# SQL: Insert into table and return new index?

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a database with auto-increment index. When I inserting a new item in the table, I don't know the index number. Is there a way to return new index of my item simultaneously?

I could assume that the new index would be = `max-index + 1`. Is there some standard way to solve this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What DBMS or database engine (as in, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server) are you using? The ways to do what you want differ between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, you use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (auto,text) VALUES(NULL,'text');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL use `@@IDENTITY`.
For example `INSERT INTO  [TaTAble] (testchamps) VALUES (tesvaleurs); SELECT @@IDENTITY as [index];`

Comment: ... which does not deliver the expected results when triggers perform other inserts. In that case you get the auto-id of the row the trigger created. *If* you want to do that, at least use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`. *If* you assume SQL-Server look into `INSERT ... OUTPUT` to get exactly what you want. However, this question can not be answered without knowing the exact DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() after data INSERT if you use MS SQL SERVER

Example :

```
declare @new_id int

insert into test_table(col1,col2) values(col1_val,col2_val)
set @new_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

`@new_id` will be inserted index

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can also use `OUTPUT INSERTED` which in contrast to the solutions above also work when doing the query via `ODBC` from a python or julia script.

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl (auto, text) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id]
VALUES(NULL,'text');
```